# CDO.Message Addattachment

Tags: excel, vba, cdo.message

I have a problem with a code or I don't know what's it, but I will explain you, the problem is that when I download the file, that I already had sent, in my gmail account and appears that the file is damaged, so i cant see it.
It is a file*.xlsl
If someone know what is missing it or what is wrong, I would appreciate it very much.

```
Sub send_an_email()

Set MiCorreocon = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

With MiCorreocon.Fields
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'cdoBasic
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'cdoSendUsingPort
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "@gmail.com"
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "*****"
   .Update
End With

Set MiCorreo = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

Adjunto = "c:\users\" & Application.UserName & "\Documents\" & "File.xlsx"

With MiCorreo
    Set .Configuration = MiCorreocon
    .Subject = "email" 
    .From = "@gmail.com"
    .To = "@gmail.com"
    .AddAttachment Adjunto
    .Send
End With


Set MiCorreo = Nothing
Set MiCorreocon = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: use `.TextBody` before or after `.AddAttachment` and enter some content as a message to avoid such attachment behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I already done and it works, so i already can download the file without any problem. Your are a genius!